# How to install Node.js on JetBrains PhpStorm?

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I installed [**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/) and I want to install the plugin on [JetBrains PhpStorm 7.1.2](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) but when I try to install I get this error:

```
16.21.16 Plugin Error: NodeJS: C:\Users\Fuiba\.WebIde70\system\plugins\action.script (Access denied)
```

I tried to remove that script file and install but I still get the error.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by unchecking **Read-only** from `.WebIde70` folder properties.